# multiple select POST issues

Tags: php, post

## Overview

I'm currently having an issue in in PHP with POST data. I have two multiple select boxes (one on the left hand side of the screen, and the other on the right).

I then populate the option elements on the left with elements from my database, and the options on the right with data from the database. However, when I print the POST data the elements that I put into the right multiple select box are not posted (as expected).

### The code

```html
      <form method="post" action="http://">
        <div class="left">
          <label for="left">Attributes to select:</label>
          <select size="5" name="allAtts" id="toSelect" multiple=""> 
            <option value="jay">jay</option>
            <option value="bill">bill</option>
          </select>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn add">Add</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <label for="right">Attributes to store:</label>
          <select size="5" id="selectedAtts" name="selectedAtts[]" multiple="">
            <option value="bob">bob</option>
            <option value="jim">jim</option>
            <option value="frank">frank</option>
          </select>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn remove">Remove</a></p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Visualise!">
      </form>
```

### My issue

I want all of the elements in the right multiple select box to POSTED so I can store them into the database, this includes the *default* option elements (those put in by the database).

#### Further update

Note: When I select an item from the left (using my button and javascript) and move it to the right, that specific data (when the form is submitted) is posted. I want that data, but also the default options of the right multiple select.

Comment: If memory serves, only the value of the selected item in a select box is sent to the POST array. I don't think you've got the right take on your problem...unfortunately I don't really get your problem.

Comment: Make sure that names of two select boxes are different and make sure that both of them are inside of Form tag.

Comment: I want the values from my multiple select box to be sent to the POST array. The includes the values I have used already entered on page load (they're inserted by a function - the data is retrieved from the database).

Comment: Just so I got this right, you want ALL options from your select box in the POST array? If so, you've definitely got the wrong tag.

Comment: What are you getting with `print_r($_POST['elements']);`?

Comment: @MichaelRushton The POST array when printed is:

`Array ( [submit] => Visualise! )`

Comment: Did you select any values before posting?

Comment: @MichaelRushton - No. That's the issue. It already contains three values (bob, jim, frank). Thus, I want to send to POST the default values of the right multiple select.

It works if I bring values from the left multiple select to the right (via javascript).

Comment: The `$_POST` array will only contain the *selected* options. If you don't select anything then nothing will be posted.

Comment: @MichaelRushton Then how can I force the data I put into the right div to automatically be selected? So that it can be send to the POST array. (javaScript?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want every option in the `selectedAtts` dropdown to be passed to the `$_POST` array you need to actually select them. So add the `selected` attribute to each option.

```
      <select size="5" id="selectedAtts" name="selectedAtts[]" multiple="">
        <option selected value="bob">bob</option>
        <option selected value="jim">jim</option>
        <option selected value="frank">frank</option>
      </select>
```

Of course, nothing (as the code currently stands) is to stop the user from deselecting any or all of the options...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the right multiple select box in the posted data, you may want to print them as input hidden, and then use that for your job. Keep in mind though, that advanced users may alter your data, if you implement it the way that I am suggesting.